# Equivalent of STP16C596 in DIP package for through-mount

Tags: arduino, led

I’m trying to add a large number of RGB LEDs (70, so 210 outputs) in a fairly small space (basically a keyboard, although it’s a bit bigger than most).

I read on [this tutorial](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftOut) and elsewhere about shift registers, and to me the STP16C596 seems particularly good because a) it will drive 16 outputs and b) it obviates the need for resistors because it provides a constant current.

However, this part is obsolete it would seem and unavailable. What’s a good alternative that I will still be able to hand-solder?

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/best-way-to-control-75-leds-with-arduino) suggests using an ‘SCT2026’, but the original link is dead, and I get no result on Mouser or Digikey for that part.

**Notes**

Apologies if any of my terminology is not right – I’m new to this!

I would certainly consider alternative approaches to this problem if there are any. From what I can see, a matrix-based or charlieplexing approach would be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the [STP16CP05](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00126634.pdf) for shift-register type environments (as an SOIC chip - not through hole, but easy to hand solder anyway).

For more complex environments requiring PWM I use the I2C controlled [TLC59116](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc59116.pdf). I use it as a TSSOP, but I believe it's available as PDIP.

Both are LED drivers and control up to 16 LEDs each.

Comment: Ah, okay, I wasn’t aware that SOIC could still be hand-soldered. I guess it’s large enough despite no being through-hole right?

Comment: TBH I find SOIC chunky.  As long as your PCB is good enough and you have a good flux pen you can hand solder TSSOP, TQFP, etc.  I regularly hand solder 0.4mm pitch TQFPs with a normal soldering iron.

Comment: This is how new I am to this – I’d never heard of a flux pen before, I’ve just been using solder. Okay, I’m going to get hold of a few of these things and give them all a try.

Comment: The flux pen is the single most important accessory for the hand solderer.  I use the SMF12P from ElectroLube.

Comment: That’s really useful, thanks for the advice. I’m just checking out how to use these – does this type of flux pen require cleaning afterwards?

Comment: It doesn't *need* cleaning, but I do clean it anyway - I tend to use large amounts and it leaves it a bit sticky. Isopropyl alcohol is best for cleaning I find.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should consider something with a little more "oomph", such as the [TLC5940](http://www.ti.com/product/tlc5940). It's a little harder to use than just a shift register, but a lot more flexible.

Comment: Fantastic, I’d not seen this and its siblings mentioned, looks like it might be worth making the step up for the on-board PWM and dimming.